# Exclude one item with different corelated value in the next column SQL

Tags: sql, not-exists

I have two tables:

| acc_num | ser_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 1 | C |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | D |

and the second one is:

| ser_code | value |
| --- | --- |
| A | 5 |
| B | 8 |
| C | 10 |
| D | 15 |

I want to exclude all the accounts with the service codes that they have value of 10 or 15.
Because my data set is huge, I want to use NOT EXIST but it just excludes combination of acc_num and ser_code.
I want to exclude the acc_num with all of it's ser_code, because on of it's ser_code meats my criteria.

I used: 
select acc_num, ser_code 
from table 1 
where NOT EXIST (select 1 
FROM table 2 where acc_num = acc_num and value in (10, 15)

out put with above code is:

| acc_num | ser_code |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |

**Desire out put would be empty.**

Comment: Which rdms are you using?

Comment: Oracle and Microsoft SQL Server database

Comment: Does `select distinct acc_num from table2 where value in (10, 15)` return acc_num you want to filter out? Then it is easy to incorporate it in your query: `where acc_num not in (select distinct acc_num from table2 where value in (10, 15))`

Answer (score 0):

here you are

```
select t1.acc_num,t1.ser_code from table1 t1, table2 t2 
where (t1.ser_code=t2.ser_code and  t2.value not in (10,15)) 
and t1.acc_num  not in 
(
    select t3.acc_num from table1 t3,table2 t4 
    where t1.acc_num=t3.acc_num and t3.ser_code=t4.ser_code 
    and  t4.value  in (10,15)
) ;
```

Answer (score 0):

This could be achieved in many ways. However using `NOT EXISTS` is the best option. The problem with your query is for `acc_num` 1, there are `ser_code` that does not have value as 10, 15. So you will get `A` and `B` in result.

To overcome that you must pull `acc_num` inside the `sub-query`

**Query 1 (using NOT EXISTS):**

As you can see in the below query, I have included `acc_num` inside `sub-query`, so that the filter works properly,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.acc_num, a.ser_code 
FROM one as a
WHERE NOT EXISTS
       (
       SELECT DISTINCT one.acc_num 
       FROM two 
       INNER JOIN one
           ON one.ser_code=two.ser_code
       WHERE value IN (10,15) AND a.acc_num=one.acc_num
       )
```

**Query 2 (using LEFT JOIN):**

NOT EXISTS often confusing due to it's nature (super `fast` though). Hence `LEFT JOIN` could also be used (expensive than `NOT EXISTS`),

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.acc_num, a.ser_code 
FROM one as a
LEFT JOIN 
       (
       SELECT DISTINCT one.acc_num 
       FROM two 
       INNER JOIN one
           ON one.ser_code=two.ser_code
       WHERE value IN (10,15)
       ) b
   ON a.acc_num=b.acc_num
WHERE b.acc_num IS NULL
```

**Query 3 (using NOT IN):**

`NOT IN` would also achieve this with comprehensive query but expensive than both of the above methods,

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.acc_num, a.ser_code 
FROM one as a
WHERE a.acc_num NOT IN
       (
       SELECT DISTINCT one.acc_num 
       FROM two 
       INNER JOIN one
           ON one.ser_code=two.ser_code
       WHERE value IN (10,15)
       )
```

All 3 would yield same result. I would prefer to go with ***NOT EXISTS***

See demo with time consumption in *[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=d164ea429bc847111124f302292c482e)*